# How to execute another job after a background job?

Tags: function, nested, dolphindb

I want to execute the following jobs:

1. Use `scheduleJob` to run `job1` at a specific time, such as 09:25m, and
   set the parameter *onComplete* to `function1`;
2. Within `function1`, define func2 and call `submitJobEx` to submit `job2`
   where `function2` is executed.
3. After `submitJobEx`, use `getJobReturn` to get the output of `job2`.
4. Continue running `job3`.

How can I achieve the workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining one method within another method, such as defining `function2` within `function1`, is not supported in DolphinDB. It is recommended to use a scheduling framework like Airflow to schedule and manage workflows. For complex workflows, an external scheduling system should be used. DolphinDB supports the Airflow plugin.